# POI-XSSF: cell type is FORMULA, but not able to get cachedResultType

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

In my code, i am checking for the cell type and if the cell type is formula, then i am trying to get the cached value, like this:

```
else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA){
        System.out.println("formula result type:" +cell.getCachedFormulaResultType());
        switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()){
            case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    ....    
                    ....        
            break;
```

It works fine for some cells, but in one of the cells, i get ILLEGAL STATE EXCEPTION:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only formula cells have cached results
```

I am not able to find out the cause for the error.
I am not using `cell.getCachedFormulaResult()` outside of this `else if`, and even this works for all of the preceding cells (which have the same formula)

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Also please add the full stacktrace so we see where exactly the Exception is thrown

Answer (score 1):

If the cached result is not available, maybe it helps to trigger the computation explicitly:

```
Workbook wb = ...
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

// suppose your formula is in B3
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3"); 
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```

You could do something like this e.g. inside a `try/catch(IllegalStateException)`

Comment: I do not need to trigger the computation, as the excel uses some third party library for formulae, which is not available to me as a plugin, that is why i just read the cached value. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I was also facing the same issue with my XLSM file.

You said,

"and even this works for all of the preceding cells (which have the same formula)".

As per https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57798,
*The method cell.getCachedFormulaResultType() returns an exception when the cell is part of an array formula and is not the first cell of the array formula.*

In my case, there were old versions of the poi and related jars lying scattered across many folders. That was causing the issue even though I had also added the latest jars.
So I did some cleaning-up and that fixed the issue for me. Hope this helps someone.